# Stata: How can I generate a dataset from the results of a case-control study?

Tags: stata

I have the following results that I'd like to put into Stata and run some analysis:

[image: Case control data]

Is there a way I can generate the dataset for this data in Stata so that there are the appropriate number of observations, allowing me to run `tabodds` or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for.

```
clear
set obs 6
gen region = word("`c(ALPHA)'", ceil(_n / 2))
bysort region : gen control = _n - 1
label define casecontrol 1 "Control" 0 "Case"
label values control casecontrol
local expandlist 708 1392 946 2086 328 996
gen exp = real(word("`expandlist'", _n))
expand exp
drop exp
tab region control
```

Result:

```
. tab region control

           |        control
    region |      Case    Control |     Total
-----------+----------------------+----------
         A |       708      1,392 |     2,100 
         B |       946      2,086 |     3,032 
         C |       328        996 |     1,324 
-----------+----------------------+----------
     Total |     1,982      4,474 |     6,456
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Wouter, this helps a lot and I was able to run my chi-squared trend test. However, I'm struggling to apply this to other situations - how would I adapt it to be for a 2x2 table (a binary variable say, rather than 3 regions)? I tried changing bysort region to be something like _n / 2 or _n - 2 but that's clearly not right.

Comment: The most important thing is to set the right amount of initial observations, one for each combination of variables. So 2x2 implies `set obs 4`. Just changing that would already work. If you want a 0 1 indicator variable instead of region A B you could change `gen region = word("\`c(ALPHA)'", ceil(_n / 2))` to something like `gen region = mod(_n, 2)`